# Can we load data into any of the database using kafkastreams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka streams to fetch the data from a topic and now I would like to load these data to Postgres. Is it possible?

Comment: You could try using kafka connect to move data from kafka topics into other persistent stores. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams is a 'small footprint' client libraries meant only to work with data from kafka to kafka. To copy data from / into kafka you should use kafka connect , or building your own kafka consumer/producer ,